# Calculate eigenvalues of $\begin{bmatrix}x & 9\\4 & x\end{bmatrix}$ as a function of $x$

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, determinant

> Calculate eigenvalues of $$\begin{bmatrix}x & 9\\4 & x\end{bmatrix}$$ as a function of $x$.

---

$$A = \left|{\begin{bmatrix}
        x & 9 \\
        4 & x 
        \end{bmatrix}
        -\lambda \begin{bmatrix}
        1 & 0 \\
        0 & 1
        \end{bmatrix} }\right|=\left|{\begin{bmatrix}
        x-\lambda & 9 \\
        4 & x-\lambda
        \end{bmatrix} }\right|$$

$ = (x-\lambda)(x-\lambda) - (9\times4)=x^2-2\lambda x + \lambda^2-36 $

$\rightarrow x^2-2\lambda x + \lambda^2-36=0\rightarrow x^2-2\lambda x + \lambda^2=36$

$\rightarrow (x-\lambda)^2=36$

So far here is where I got. I use the fact that the determinant must equal $0$ and I'm stuck at this point where I can't strictly solve for $\lambda$, because of the variable $x$.

Comment: The problem statement in the first line is very strangely phrased. Are you sure you're quoting it correctly? Where are you quoting _from_? There seems to be a grammatical object missing -- solve _what_?

Comment: @Troposphere sorry corrected it

Comment: You have to solve for $\lambda$ in terms of $x$.  Just pretend $x$ is some known number.

Comment: @saulspatz yes exactly

Comment: $x-\lambda = \pm 6 \implies \lambda = x \mp 6$ (where are you stuck?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$ \lambda^{2} -2\lambda x + x^{2}-36=0 $$
$$ \Delta=4x^{2} -4(x^{2}-36)=4*36 \Longrightarrow \sqrt{\Delta}=12 \Longrightarrow \lambda _{1}=x-6 \wedge \lambda _{2}=x+6  $$

Answer (score 1):

When $x=0$ the matrix $M(0)$ has trace $0$ and determinant $-36$, so eigenvalues are $6$ and $-6$. For arbitrary $x$, the matrix is $M(x)=M(0)+xId$, so it has eigenvalues that are shifted by $x$ from those of $M(0)$, i.e. $x+6$ and $x-6$.